# Parametized SQL Query with unlimited parameters

Tags: c#, sql, database, vb.net, parameterized

I've heard of parametized sql queries a long time ago but I never really gave any attention to it as I'm used to writing full sql statements. I know it improves security against sql injection so now might be a very good time to adapt change even if it's too late. I got this one from this site http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html. So all credits go to the author. I've noticed all examples of parametized sql queries have paremeter count limitations. An example is the one shown below.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
conn.Open();
string s = "SELECT email, passwd, login_id, full_name FROM members WHERE email = @email";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", email);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

This is just equivalent to

```
SELECT email, passwd, login_id, full_name FROM members WHERE email = 'x';
```

I've learned programming all on my own through reading online tutorials and I really got nobody to help me on this. The reason I got stuck with full sql statement queries is the fact that I can't figure out how to do parametized sql queries with unlimited parameters. Is there any way to do this? The example only accepts 1 parameter which is the 'email' field. And it selects 4 fields from the given sql statement. My question is... is there any way we can do parametized sql queries with 5, 6, 7, or 100 selected fields, as well as the conditions under the WHERE clause? If this is possible, it will be particularly helpful when using INSERT statement. Thank you very much.

This example is in C#, but any VB.NET or same C# implementations are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: First of all, kudos for learning, keep it up. Second I'm not entirely sure I understand your issue ? If you specify a parameter you need to specify it by name (you need it to specify the column in the `where` clause anyway) ?

Comment: You can use a lot of parameters, but there is a limit.  If you are using sql server as your database, the limit is 2100.

Comment: Are you actually talking about the selected columns ? You can always do `SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = @email`

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov, your statement about having to specify parameters by name is not always true.

Comment: @DanBracuk Yes, but you have to specify the column name anyway. I don't see how you can skip that part.

Comment: Hi @DimitarDimitrov :) Thank you very much for your comments. Yeah I've been programming hardware and software stuff from robotics, microcontrollers and electronics to pure software implementations on my own but I still got a gazillion to learn. Thank you for the encouragement :) Yes we can always use * but that's only for SELECT. What I mean is... what if I want to use "INSERT INTO TABLE1(F1,F2,F3) VALUES ('1','2','3')" and I want to use parametized sql queries. I'd like to have the same function to insert into database regardless of the number of values to insert.

Comment: In other words, is it possible to implement a function that accepts unlimited number of parameters just by specifying the table name you want and the values you want to insert? @Dan Bracuk, I understand the server database limitation, but I don't mean that part :) Thank you for that info anyway.

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov, in .net, which this question is about, you don't always use named parameters.  There are occasions where you use positional parameters.  One such occasion is if you are using an odbc connection to an Oracle database.

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution would be to pass the parameters name and value using a [Dictionary object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). A Dictionary object holds a collection of **keys** and **values**, and this is exactly what a single [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is - a single Key/Value container in the form:

```
Key = @Value
```

A collection can hold an arbitrary count of items, for example:

```
new Dictionary<String, Object> 
{
    { "@Name", "Anonymous" },
    { "@Age", 25 },
    { "@Street", "Highway" },
    { "@Number", "1001" },
    { "@City", "NoName" }
}
```

In the example above, the *key* is of type String and the *value* of type Object. Object allows parameter values of arbitrary types (the explanation comes later in the code examples).

One possibility to create dynamic SQL statements would be:

- extract the repetitive tasks, for example the creation of the [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and the passing of the parameters to the SqlCommand variable
- create parametrised *dynamic* SQL query string for the wanted SQL command

The code can look like this:

```
// extract all repetitive tasks

// Create an array of SqlParameters from the given Dictionary object.
// The parameter value is of type Object in order to allow parameter values of arbitrary types!
// The .NET Framework converts the value automatically to the correct DB type. 
// MSDN info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y%28v=vs.110%29.aspx 
private SqlParameter[] dictionaryToSqlParameterArray(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    var sqlParameterCollection = new List<SqlParameter>();
    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
    {
        sqlParameterCollection.Add(new SqlParameter(parameter.Key, parameter.Value));
    }
    return sqlParameterCollection.ToArray();
}

// sqlQuery is the complete parametrised query
// for example like: INSERT INTO People(Name, Age, Street) VALUES(@Name, @Age, @Street)
private SqlCommand createSqlCommand(String sqlQuery, Dictionary<String, object> parameters)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery);
    command.Parameters.AddRange(dictionaryToSqlParameterArray(parameters));
    return command;
}
```

Now a call with dynamic count of parameters will look like this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
string sqlQuery = "SELECT email, passwd, login_id, full_name FROM members WHERE email = @email AND name = @name";
// using the newly created method instead of adding/writing every single parameter manually
SqlCommand command = createSqlCommand(sqlQuery, new Dictionary<String, Object>
                                                    {
                                                        { "@email", "test@test.com" },
                                                        { "@name", "test" }
                                                    });
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

It is a good start, but this is still not very dynamic, since we need to write the complete query every time (we save only the typing of *command.Parameters.Add*). Let's change this in order to type even less:

```
// create a parametrised SQL insert command with arbitrary count of parameters for the given table
private SqlCommand createSqlInsert(String tableName, Dictionary<String, object> parameters)
{
    // the sql insert command pattern
    var insertQuery = @"INSERT INTO {0}({1}) VALUES({2})";
    // comma separated column names like: Column1, Column2, Column3, etc.
    var columnNames = parameters.Select (p => p.Key.Substring(1)).Aggregate ((h, t) => String.Format("{0}, {1}", h, t));
    // comma separated parameter names like: @Parameter1, @Parameter2, etc.
    var parameterNames = parameters.Select (p => p.Key).Aggregate ((h, t) => String.Format("{0}, {1}", h, t));
    // build the complete query
    var sqlQuery = String.Format(insertQuery, tableName, columnNames, parameterNames);
    // debug
    Console.WriteLine(sqlQuery);
    // return the new dynamic query
    return createSqlCommand(sqlQuery, parameters);
}

// create a parametrised SQL select/where command with arbitrary count of parameters for the given table
private SqlCommand createSqlWhere(String tableName, Dictionary<String, object> parameters)
{
    // the sql select command pattern
    var whereQuery = @"SELECT * FROM {0} WHERE {1}";
    // sql where condition like: Column1 = @Parameter1 AND Column2 = @Parameter2 etc.
    var whereCondition = parameters.Select (p => String.Format("{0} = {1}", p.Key.Substring(1), p.Key)).Aggregate ((h, t) => String.Format("{0} AND {1}", h, t));
    // build the complete condition
    var sqlQuery = String.Format(whereQuery, tableName, whereCondition);
    // debug
    Console.WriteLine(sqlQuery);
    // return the new dynamic query
    return createSqlCommand(sqlQuery, parameters);
}
```

Now the creation of a *SELECT* command will look like this:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
// specify only table name and arbitrary count of parameters
var getPersonSqlCommand = createSqlWhere("People", new Dictionary<String, Object> 
                                                    {
                                                        { "@Name", "J.D." },
                                                        { "@Age", 30 }
                                                    });
SqlDataReader reader = getPersonSqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

The **createSqlWhere** method will return an initialized SqlCommand with the query:

```
SELECT * FROM People WHERE Name = @Name AND Age = @Age
```

The **INSERT** will also be short:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();
// specify only table name and arbitrary count of parameters
var addPersonSqlCommand = createSqlInsert("People", new Dictionary<String, Object> 
                                                {
                                                    { "@Name", "Anonymous" },
                                                    { "@Age", 25 },
                                                    { "@Street", "Test" }
                                                });
addPersonSqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The corresponding SQL command will look like this:

```
INSERT INTO People(Name, Age, Street) VALUES(@Name, @Age, @Street)
```

Other SQL commands like DELETE, UPDATE and so on can be created in the same way. New parameters should be added only in one place - in the dictionary.

Admittedly the initial effort is more than just **writing one method**, but it will pay off if the new methods are used more than once (a couple of times) - for example five parametrised selects and/or inserts on five different tables with different parameters, which is certainly always the case in small and average sized software projects.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a method like :

```
    public void unlimQuery(string query,params object[] args)
       {
          SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
          conn.Open();
          string s =query;
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s);
          For(int i=0;i<  args.Length;i++)
          cmd.Parameters.Add("@param"+i, args[i]);
          SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
```

Example :

```
     unlimQuery("INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS(ID,NAME,AGE,ADRESS,COUNTRY) VALUES(@param0,@param1,@param2,@param3,@param4)",5,"Ali",27,"my City","England");
```

Explanation :

the params keyword in c# gives you the possibility to insert unlimited arguments of the indicated type, so the arguments added (5,"Ali",27,"my City","England") will be casted to an array of objects then passed to the Method

inside the method you'll get an array of objects, so for each object you create a parameter, his alias is `@paramX` where X is the index of the argument (in the params array), then sqlCommad will replace each alias by its value defined in the `cmd.Parameters.Add("@param"+i, args[i])` clause

so @param0 => 5, .....

Comment: Hi @Badik Ali, Thank you for helping, I appreciate it very much. I will try this. Nonetheless, would it be alright if you can give an INSERT query example of this? I should be able to make UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT by editing your INSERT example, if it's possible ;) Thank you.

Comment: @chris_techno25 just replace the parameters by the args order

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean for the implementation, mind if you explain a bit more? Thank you.

Comment: This example is nonsense - the column names are static **ID,NAME,AGE,ADRESS,COUNTRY**, so if you pass 50 parameters they would map to what columns? A possible approach would be to pass a Dictionary(any Key/Value pair container) and build the Parameters using the given Key for parameter name and Value for parameter value.

Comment: @pasty the question started with how to pass unlimited parameters, also if you have 50 parameters as you said, as long as you write the query there'll be no problem

Comment: Sorry, but this does not exuse code that does not work and is wrong! SO is also about helping people with less experience to improve their programming skills, so IMO one should not just code for the points but think about a good *and working* answer.

Comment: @pasty so please do answer this question with a better solution, because using a dictionary will complicate the situation and here why whould I need a pair Key/Value, so I have to write my query, name the parameters then create for each name a pair key/value, then add it to the dictionary, ... !!!

Comment: Guys, there's no need to argue :) We're all friends here. You both know a lot more than I do, and thank you so much for helping. But I'd have to say pasty got my point, though he presented a more complicated solution which I didn't expect. I will test this solution. @Badik Ali, thank you for your help. You gave me another idea too. But pasty is right, your current solution doesn't really accept 'unlimited' parameters since the column names are static. It shouldn't be any different if I just used values to be inserted directly. Thank you.

Comment: Slightly off-topic but the "string s =query;" statement in your answer is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

i think you just have to change this

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", email);
```

to

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
```